# Call selector within NSPredicate

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate

I need a way to call a selector within NSPredicate. I have an array of MyElement objects. One property of MyElement is "keywords" which is simply an array of strings. Currently I prepare a predicate to find a set of MyElements containing a particular keyword (somewhere in each MyElement's keyword array):

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN keywords", someString];
```

Since keywords is a property of MyElement (of type NSArray) it all works great. However, now I need to do some manipulation of the array before it comes back to the predicate. Something like:

```
NSString* key = // a key used to help shape the array
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN keywordsSpecialArray:key", someString];
```

This needs to call keywordsSpecialArray:key in each MyElement which will return a massaged array. This array is a slightly modified version of the array that would have been returned by just using @"%@ IN keywords".

What is the right syntax to do this?

Comment: If `key` is a property of `MyElement` you can add a calculated property `massagedKeywords` which returns `[self keywordsSpecialArray:self.key]`.

Comment: It's not. Not that it really matters to this, but the above is a simplified version. In reality, MyElement has a property called userFields which is an NSDictionary using UUIDs as keys and NSStrings as values. MyElement implements valueForUndefinedKey to get at these fields which just looks up the value in my dictionary. Sometimes I want that field directly as a string but sometimes I need it massaged as an array. keywordsSpecialArray:key is supposed to get the field string for key (passing through valueForUndefinedKey) and then massage the results into a special array.

Comment: I end up getting: Unable to parse the format string "%@ IN keywordsSpecialArray:%K". Note that the "key" has to be dynamic, thus the %K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN FUNCTION(self, 'keywordsSpecialArray:', %@)", value, key];
```